# How to build a nested object in jsonb C function?

Tags: c, postgresql, jsonb

I am able to build and return a simple `jsonb` object, but i'm stuck on trying to use a nested object as a value.

For example, I would like to return the `jsonb` object:

```
{"one":1.0,"nest":{"a":1.0,"b":2.0}}
```

The following code returns the error `unknown type of jsonb container` specifically on this line:

```
result.res = pushJsonbValue(&result.parseState, WJB_VALUE, &obj_val);
```

Here is my current code:

```
Datum
build_a_nested_object(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{

    Datum num_val;
    JsonbInState result, nested_result;
    JsonbValue key, val, obj_val;

    memset(&result, 0, sizeof(JsonbInState));
    result.res = pushJsonbValue(&result.parseState, WJB_BEGIN_OBJECT, NULL);

    // first key
    key.type = jbvString;
    key.val.string.len = 3;
    key.val.string.val = "one";
    result.res = pushJsonbValue(&result.parseState, WJB_KEY, &key);

    // first value
    val.type = jbvNumeric;
    num_val = DirectFunctionCall3(numeric_in, CStringGetDatum("1.0"), ObjectIdGetDatum(InvalidOid), Int32GetDatum(-1));
    val.val.numeric = DatumGetNumeric(num_val);
    result.res = pushJsonbValue(&result.parseState, WJB_VALUE, &val);

    // Second key
    key.type = jbvString;
    key.val.string.len = 4;
    key.val.string.val = "nest";
    result.res = pushJsonbValue(&result.parseState, WJB_KEY, &key);

    // Second value
    memset(&nested_result, 0, sizeof(JsonbInState));
    nested_result.res = pushJsonbValue(&nested_result.parseState, WJB_BEGIN_OBJECT, NULL);

    // First nested key
    key.type = jbvString;
    key.val.string.len = 1;
    key.val.string.val = "a";
    nested_result.res = pushJsonbValue(&nested_result.parseState, WJB_KEY, &key);

    // First nested value
    val.type = jbvNumeric;
    numd = DirectFunctionCall3(numeric_in, CStringGetDatum("1.0"), ObjectIdGetDatum(InvalidOid), Int32GetDatum(-1));
    val.val.numeric = DatumGetNumeric(numd);
    nested_result.res = pushJsonbValue(&nested_result.parseState, WJB_VALUE, &val);

    // Second nested key
    key.type = jbvString;
    key.val.string.len = 1;
    key.val.string.val = "b";
    nested_result.res = pushJsonbValue(&nested_result.parseState, WJB_KEY, &key);

    // Second nested value
    val.type = jbvNumeric;
    numd = DirectFunctionCall3(numeric_in, CStringGetDatum("2.0"), ObjectIdGetDatum(InvalidOid), Int32GetDatum(-1));
    val.val.numeric = DatumGetNumeric(numd);
    nested_result.res = pushJsonbValue(&nested_result.parseState, WJB_VALUE, &val);

    nested_result.res = pushJsonbValue(&nested_result.parseState, WJB_END_OBJECT, NULL);
    obj_val.type = jbvBinary;
    obj_val.val.binary.data = JsonbValueToJsonb(nested_result.res);

    result.res = pushJsonbValue(&result.parseState, WJB_VALUE, &obj_val);
    result.res = pushJsonbValue(&result.parseState, WJB_END_OBJECT, NULL);

    PG_RETURN_POINTER(JsonbValueToJsonb(result.res));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

demo, build jsonb:  `{"hello": 11, "world": {"in_the_nested": 1111}}`.

`{"hello": 11, "world": {"in_the_nested": 1111}}`
same as the following query.

`select(jsonb_build_object('hello',11,'world',jsonb_build_object('in_the_nested',111)));`

```c
#include "postgres.h"

#include "utils/builtins.h"
#include "utils/array.h"
#include "funcapi.h"
#include "utils/lsyscache.h"
#include "utils/fmgrprotos.h"
#include "utils/jsonb.h"
#include "utils/numeric.h"

PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(build_nested_jsonb);

/*
select (jsonb_build_object('hello',11,'world',jsonb_build_object('in_the_nested',111)));
*/

Datum 
build_nested_jsonb(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    Datum      *args;
    bool       *nulls;
    Oid        *types;
    Jsonb       *jsonbp;

    args    = (Datum *) palloc(4 * sizeof(Datum));
    nulls   = (bool *) palloc(4 * sizeof(bool));
    types   = (Oid *)  palloc(4 *  sizeof(Oid));
    jsonbp  = (Jsonb *) palloc(1 * sizeof(Jsonb));

    char    *key        = "hello";
    int     value       = 11;
    char    *nested     = "world";
    char    *nested1    = "in_the_nested";
    int     value1      = 1111;

    args[0]     =   CStringGetDatum(key);
    nulls[0]    =   false;
    types[0]    =   CSTRINGOID;

    args[1]     =   Int32GetDatum(value);
    nulls[1]    =   false;
    types[1]    =   INT4OID;

    args[2]     =   CStringGetDatum(nested);
    nulls[2]    =   false;
    types[2]    =   CSTRINGOID;

    elog(NOTICE,"before palloc jsonbPair");
    JsonbPair   *pair   = palloc(1 * sizeof(JsonbPair));
    pair->key.type              = jbvString;
    pair->key.val.string.len    = (int) (strlen(nested1) + 1);
    pair->key.val.string.val    = nested1;
    pair->value.type            = jbvNumeric;
    (pair->value.val.numeric)   = int64_to_numeric((int64) value1);

    elog(NOTICE,"before palloc jsonbvalue");
    JsonbValue  *obj    = palloc(1 * sizeof(JsonbValue));
    obj->type   = jbvObject;
    obj->val.object.nPairs  = 1;
    obj->val.object.pairs  = pair;
    
    elog(NOTICE,"before construct nested jsonb");
    args[3]     =   JsonbPGetDatum(JsonbValueToJsonb(obj));
    nulls[3]    =   false;
    types[3]    =   JSONBOID;

    elog(NOTICE,"before last function call");
    PG_RETURN_DATUM(jsonb_build_object_worker(4, args, nulls, types, false, false));
}
```

jsonb_build_object_worker info:
https://doxygen.postgresql.org/jsonb_8c.html#a3ead6b3c571010f6a947998bd0ec1b11